# PushNotification through XMPP

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am making a chat app. In this I want when user's app is closed, so user may get message notification. For this I found 2 links.
1 is [GCM Cloud Connection Server (XMPP)](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#implement) and 2nd is [Upstream Messages With Google Cloud Messaging.](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/upstream_messages_with_google_cloud_messaging/) I studied both ways

In first way I only inserted

```
static {

        ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(GCM_ELEMENT_NAME, GCM_NAMESPACE,
            new PacketExtensionProvider() {
                @Override
                public PacketExtension parseExtension(XmlPullParser parser) throws
                        Exception {
                    String json = parser.nextText();
                    return new GcmPacketExtension(json);
                }
            });
    }
```

and I got this error

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   addExtensionProvider(String, String, Object) from the type
>   ProviderManager

In 2nd one I studied and implemented **Send messages upstream.** The code here used for sending message upstream is mentioned below.

```
gcm.send(projectId + "@gcm.googleapis.com", msgId,
         Constants.GCM_DEFAULT_TTL, data);
```

It says

> Google then processes the message and sends it to your backend

here I haven't mentioned any http address of my server, not getting how it will reach to my server.

So my requirement is **I want when user's app is closed, then user may get message notification.** Can anyone suggest any good tutorial or example that how can I achieve this

Comment: The Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Cloud Connection Server (CCS) is an XMPP endpoint that provides a persistent, asynchronous, bidirectional connection to Google servers......Meaning you server application will create a continuous connection to GCM, your server application is just another client application

Comment: For the `chatApp` and `GCM Cloud Connection Server (XMPP) `, you may refer to [here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-with-google-gcm-xmpp/) to get some ideas.